# Including content types in a theme?

Tags: theming, nodes

If I'm making a theme that I want multiple people to be able to download and install (not just making it for one client), what's the best way to include the content types? For instance, say it's a portfolio type of website, and has a content type called "project". I don't want anyone who downloads my theme to have to go in and create the content types by hand.

What are best practices in distributing a theme with requirements like that? Is there a simple module I could expect someone to install first?

Comment: How does it makes sense for a _theme_ to ship with content types? It sounds more like you should be building an install profile that uses your theme.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme code depends on certain content types being there, then that tells me that you are actually building a module plus a theme, and not just a standalone theme.

One way to do this is to use the Features module to [export your content types and other settings](http://drupal.org/node/580026). Then you probably want to move some of your theme functions into the module code, so that other themers can more easily build on top of what you've created.